# how to layout my Rust modules in src for access across my application

Tags: rust

I have created a package structure but the compiler says it can't find my module. I am new to rust, with a background in Java & C#

I have tried using self and super prefixes but can't get the code to compile

I have the following structure:

```
src
|_lib.rs
|_common
| |_mod.rs
| |_service.rs
|
|_animals
  |_mod.rs
  |_domestic
  | |_mod.rs
  | |_dog.rs
  |_wild
  |_mod.rs
```

here are the simplified files:

dog.rs

```
pub struct Dog {
  ...
}

impl Dog {
    ...
}
```

domestic > mod.rs

```
pub mod dog;
```

animals > mod.rs

```
pub mod domestic;
pub mod wild;
```

src > lib.rs

```
pub mod common;
pub mod animals;
```

common > service

```
use animals::domestic::dog;
```

From what I have read (and possibly misunderstood) in the Rust book, this should work.

But the compiler throws the following error:

```
could not find `animals` in `{{root}}`
```

Have I set this out in a 'Rust' way? and what do I need to change to get it to compile.

Thank you

Comment: Do you not have a `src/lib.rs`?

Comment: Yes, I do have a __lib.rs__. I have added it to the description. just an oversight when I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `commons > service`

```
use crate::animals::domestic::dog;
```

The `crate` keyword tells the compiler to start from the root of the package; i.e. what follows is an absolute path.

Alternatively, you can go with relative paths and use the `super` keyword to go one level up.

See [this Rust book entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html) for details